# How to detect device rotation despite locked display orientation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opengl-es

So I have an app that needs to not use autorotate. Instead of rotating the screen the buttons on the screen are just supposed to rotate.

I have the interface locked in landscape left. How do I detect what rotation the buttons should be?

I am using a custom opengl engine so I can set the rotation of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the device orientation from:

```
UIDevice.orientation
```

This is not the interface orientation, so you get two more possible values for face up and face down. Also the landscape left and right are swapped compared to `UIInterfaceOrientation`.

You can listen for changes in device orientation by subscribing to the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` notification from `NSNotificationCenter`. You may have to enable these notifications by calling `UIDevice.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()`.

Comment: That notification no longer exist

Answer (score 0):

**If** the interface **orientation** is **locked** on the device, it **is not listening to any delegate methods** related to orientation changes.

Comment: I am not using UI kit. I have objects that I can set the rotation values for.

Comment: What kit you're using? You should mention that.

Comment: Open Gl Es 2.0. If I can figure out the orientation the device thinks it should be in I can draw it so

Comment: That's true. Why haven't you provide your question with such important information?